# Upload document using 2 legged oauthentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, google-docs-api

I was working with **.NET Google Document List API** and found stuck myself somewhere.

I want to upload a document using **2 Legged OAuthentication** as I have register my application in Google Marketplace, then install it to my domain.

Now I am using 2 legged OAuthentication to interact with data stored in google and working fine.

```
RequestSettings settings = new RequestSettings(APPLICATION_NAME, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, currentUser, DOMAIN);
```

Below is my code which is not working and gives **401 unauthorized** error:

```
GOAuthRequestFactory requestFactory = new GOAuthRequestFactory("cl", APPLICATION_NAME);
requestFactory.ConsumerKey = CONSUMER_KEY;
requestFactory.ConsumerSecret = CONSUMER_SECRET;
DocumentsService service = new DocumentsService(APPLICATION_NAME);
service.RequestFactory = requestFactory;
service.UploadFile(fileNameWithPath, fileName, contentType, false);
```